# Unity5.5.2(Unet)-Android Clients (Galaxy Tab A sm t280)sometimes not rendering scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, client, rendering, unity3d-unet

I have a multiplayer game build in Unity 5.5.2 using unet. My client builds are running on Galaxy Tab A (model sm-t280)s, and the server is a standalone window app. I have a problem where sometimes the tablets don't render anything upon connecting to the client. I can tell through debugging that they do successfully connect, but sometimes instead of rendering the single quad with a mobile unlit texture shader on it that should be there, the tablets just hang on the camera clearing color. I can run the same build multiple times and get different behavior on these tablets- sometimes they'll show the quad, other times, just color. I can't sense any pattern. Any suggestions would be great. I have minimized the client scene to just one quad and the simples image texture possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your code nor your approach that how are you making the network b/w cellular and desktop device but for the note you should keep in mind that:

> The Unity iOS/Android Networking engine is fully compatible with
>   networking for desktop devices, so your existing networking code
>   should work on iOS/Android devices. However, you may want to
>   re-engineer your code if it is mainly to be used with Wi-Fi or
>   cellular networks. Moreover, depending on the mobile, the networking
>   chip may also be the bottleneck since pings between mobile devices (or
>   between the mobile device and the desktop) are about 40–60 ms, even in
>   high performance Wi-Fi networks.
>
> Using Networking you can create a game that can be played
>   simultaneously from desktop and iOS over Wi-Fi or cellular networks.
>   In the latter case, your game server should have a public IP address
>   (accessible through the internet).
>
> Note: EDGE / 3G data connections go to sleep very quickly when no data
>   is sent. Thus sometimes you may need to “wake-up” networking. Just
>   make the WWW class connect to your site (and yield until it finishes)
>   before making the Unity networking connection..[MORE](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileNetworking.html)

So probably you should have to write some extra code to work this or require debugging.